# How do I give my label a class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uilabel

I have programmatically created a label-

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 31, y: 169, width: 258, height: 258))
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
label.text = ""
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

I have also created a Cocoa Touch Class File which is a subclass of UILabel. This file overrides the drawRect method. I want to make this file the class of the Label I created. How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of initializing UILabel, initialize the newly created class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var classLbl = YourClass()  //instead of using UILabel use your class.
classLbl.frame = CGRectMake(31, 169, 258, 258)
classLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
classLbl.text = ""
//and so on
```

Comment: The drawRect code draws a circle. I did what you said, but when I run the app, the shape is not a circle. Why is it so? @Dharmesh Kheni

Comment: import UIKit

@IBDesignable class BlackCircle: UILabel {
    

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        // Oval Drawing
        var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 258, 258))
        UIColor.blackColor().setFill()
        ovalPath.fill()
    
    }


}

Comment: just change the background color of your label like : `classLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()` and it will show circle. or don't set background color for label.

Comment: That didn't work as the drawing code wasn't executed. Also, Xcode gave me a fatal error just because I initialised the newly created class instead of initialising it with UILabel. @Dharmesh Kheni

Comment: This is my viewController code, if that helps-      var label = BlackCircle()  
    var frm = CGRect(x: 31, y: 169, width: 258, height: 258)  
    label.drawRect(frm)  
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center  
    label.text = ""  
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()  
    self.view.addSubview(label)

Comment: check out this sample project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=80400395227242152645

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked for me :) @Dharmesh Kheni

Answer (score 0):

When you are subclassing something, it means that you are "expanding" on functionality of your "parent" - in your case `UILabel` - and making a "child". There are more ways how to expand functionality of some Class, but this is most basic one.

When you create your subclass, you are basically saying "append those functions to parent", and if they are the same, override them (this is why you need `override` keyword).

In your case, you created subclass of `UILabel` probably like this:

```
class MyLabel : UILabel {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        // Your drawing code
    }
}
```

If you want to use it, you just have to allocate your variable with different class ; that of your `MyLabel`:

```
var label = MyLabel(frame: CGRectZero)
```

`MyLabel` class automatically inherits all constructors, variables and methods in `UILabel`, so you can use all previous functionality as you would before.

Note: While it is different data type, if you have method:

```
func useMyLabel(label : UILabel) {

     // Do something with my label
}
```

You can still use your object to fill "label" parameter, because it is child of UILabel. In that case, your methods that you created "extra" won't be accessible to you, unless you force type-cast the variable to your type, like this:

```
let myLabel = label as! MyLabel
```

If you want to know more about inheritance, [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) provides everything there is about how it works in swift, or [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) that is quite extensive and provide more information not only about Class inheritance.

Comment: That didn't work as the drawing code wasn't executed. Also, Xcode gave me a fatal error just because I initialised the newly created class instead of initialising it with UILabel. What's going on here? @Jiri Trecak